# How can i set a callback to run before an IEx session closes?

Tags: elixir, elixir-iex

I want to setup some cleanup code to run before a user terminates a REPL
session started with `iex -S mix`.

I was expecting that running:

```
System.at_exit fn (_) -> File.write! "afile", "it works" end
```

inside an iex session to create a file named `afile` but that doesn't seem to happen.

To be a bit more specific on what i'm trying to achieve, i start a system process inside the REPL (using `System.cmd/2`) and i want this process to be terminated when the `iex` process is terminated.

Comment: Hacking the erlang console behaviour (and Elixir just derives erlang console for `IEx`) is way too cumbersome and even often not possible. If the only thing you need is to detach a process, then detaching a process would be much easier. One might run the process with trailing ampersand `ls &` or even use [`nohup`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup).

Comment: @mudasobwa but i don't want to detach a process, i want to be able to kill it  just before my erlang process exits.

Comment: @mudasobwa I can still see the process `yes` running after exiting `iex` using `Ctrl-C Ctrl-C`.

Comment: @Dogbert `iex(1)> System.cmd "yes", []

BREAK: (a)bort (c)ontinue (p)roc info (i)nfo (l)oaded
       (v)ersion (k)ill (D)b-tables (d)istribution
^C/usr/bin/yes: %                                                                                                                                                            standard output: Broken pipe`. Am I missing smth?

Comment: @mudasobwa Looks like something is different in Linux's and OSX's `yes` (I see the same behavior as yours on Linux). Anyways, try `System.cmd "sleep", ["120"]` -- I see the same behavior for that on both Linux and OSX -- `sleep` keeps running even after exiting `iex`.

Comment: @Dogbert indeed. `yes`’ behaviour turns to be a side effect of how erlang console handles standard streams (it closes handles and `yes` does abort itself because there is no more `stdout` for it.) I will remove my first misleading comment.